# Problema al imprimir un mensaje diferente al esperado usando IF-ELSE

Tags: python, condiciones

> Tengo un programa que es una calculadora para saber si una persona esta delgada, normal, sobrepeso o obesa. Pero solo al ingresar valores de entrada que sean menores de 25 a 18.5 da como resultado Low Weight o Normal, si ingreso valores que den como resultado 25 a 30 o mayor siempre me dara Normal en vez de Overweight o Obesity.

Quisiera que me sugirieran que debo modificar o agregar para que me imprima el mensaje que deseo.

```
 weight= int(input())
 height= float(input())

 bmi= float(weight/height**2)
 print(bmi)

 if bmi < 18.5:
print("Low Weight")
 elif bmi >= 18.5 < 25:
print("Normal")
 elif bmi >= 25 < 30:
print("Overweight")
elif bmi >= 30:
print("Obesity")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que quieres obtener el Indice de Masa Corporal,
donde la formula es:
Peso en Kg / metros al cuadrado

por lo que agregué la función "pow" que multiplica al cuadrado, aunque el ** funciona bien también.

```
weight= int(input())
height= float(input())

bmi = float(weight/pow(height,2))

print(bmi)

if bmi < 18.5:
    print("Low Weight")
elif bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 25:
    print("Normal")
elif bmi >= 25 and bmi < 30:
    print("Overweight")
elif bmi >= 30:
    print("Obesity")
```

adicional cambié las condiciones del if, como lo tenías le dices:
que bmi sea mayor o igual a 18.5 y menor a 25, pero, no especificas la segunda condición.

```
 elif bmi >= 18.5 < 25:
```

por lo cual la forma correcta sería:

```
elif bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 25:
```

Comment: A ya veo no recordaba que se podia agregar and al elif para especificar la segunda condicion.

Comment: En los "elif" la primera comparación es innecesaria, pues ya diste cuenta de ella en las anteriores comparciones. Puede quedar en elif bmi < 25:` (igual en el resto)